# SAS: Retrieve a subtotal from one dataset and append it to the variables in another

Tags: sql, sas

I create a summary dataset called work.saleanalysis containing three variables and three observations:

```
Sale_Analysis             SA_Count          SA_Amount  

Beginning Sale Amount     11796             15861502.76
Redeemed                  2026               2742861.09
Final Sale Amount         9770              13118641.67
```

I create a second Summary dataset called work.removals.

```
Reason                 ES_Count             ES_Amount

Size                     1312                  316639
Value                    3101                 2083563
Type                     1211                 2418995
Other                       9                   15869
Old                        96                  154821
Bad                       245                  513487
```

I want to find out ES_Amount / SA_Amount where SA_Amount = "Final Sale Amount" and add that column to work.removals. In other words, "what percentage of the final sale amount of the whole file is included in each removal bucket?"

This exercise is super easy in excel but is proving frustrating for me in SAS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read you right, you just want one single value from Sale_Analysis copied into each row of Removals.

There are many good ways to do this, but the easiest:

```
data removals_2;
  set removals;
  if _n_=1 then set saleanalysis(where=(sale_analysis='Final Sale Amount') keep=sale_analysis sa_amount);
  drop sale_analysis;
run;
```

What you're doing is doing a second `set` statement, which grabs the variable(s) from the second dataset, and puts them on the output dataset.  Since they're only brought in once, as long as you don't have a `by` statement, they'll be retained for every row.  `if _n_=1` says to do it only on the first row (after that, you'll fail to find another row, and the datastep would terminate).

A simple example using sashelp.class:

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  if _n_=1 then set sashelp.class(where=(name_barbara='Barbara') keep=name rename=name=name_barbara);
run;
```

In general, merging data in SAS is something that you have to study as its own topic.  I'd search around the net for a good paper on the subject (either use "Combining data" or "merging data" and SAS as search terms).  It's harder than excel since you don't have direct references to other cells - but it's also far more powerful.

Comment: Magnificent! Thank you, this is perfect!!